# getting array coordinates (8 queens problem)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am trying to make a graphic program that solves the 8 queens problem and so far what i have is the chess board

```
var chessBoard:Array = new Array(); 
for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    chessBoard.push(new Array(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0));
    chessBoard.push(new Array(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1));
}

var tileSize:int = 20;

function createChessBoard():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < chessBoard.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j:int = 0; j < chessBoard[i].length; j++)
        {
            var tile:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var tileColor:int = chessBoard[i][j] * 0xffffff;

            tile.graphics.beginFill(tileColor);
            tile.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
            tile.graphics.endFill();

            tile.x = j * tileSize;
            tile.y = i * tileSize;

            addChild(tile);
        }
    }
}

createChessBoard();
```

(thanks André for this code)

this creates a black and white checkered board for the problem but now i need to be able to place the queens. How am i able to see where the user clicks in order to put the queen in the box that is clicked on?

(sorry if my question isn't fully clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a very simple example to your question. See below:

```
var chessBoard:Array = new Array(); 
for(var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    chessBoard.push(new Array(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0));
    chessBoard.push(new Array(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1));
}

var tileSize:int = 20;

function createChessBoard():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < chessBoard.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j:int = 0; j < chessBoard[i].length; j++)
        {
            var tile:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var tileColor:int = chessBoard[i][j] * 0xffffff;

            tile.graphics.beginFill(tileColor);
            tile.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
            tile.graphics.endFill();

            //I added the name property and a MouseEvent.CLICK event listener
            tile.name = "tile__" + i + "_" j + "_sp";
        tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTileClick);

            tile.x = j * tileSize;
            tile.y = i * tileSize;

            addChild(tile);
        }
    }
}

function onTileClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     //This tells you which tile the user clicked on
     trace(event.target.name);
};

createChessBoard();
```

Good luck,
Rob

Comment: thanks but also how can i add a child to one now that i know its position?

Comment: never mind i fiugred out by making a queens x and y equal to event.target.x and event.target.y it will put it directly on the tile